# Relation does not exist for Spring Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
import javax.persistence.*;

    @Table(name = "users")
    @Entity
    public class User {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "userID")
        private long userID;
    }
        
    @Table(name = "subscriptions")
    @Entity
    public class Subscription {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "subscriptionID")
        private long subscriptionID;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="userID")
        private User user;
    
    }
```

This code crashes:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation
> "subscriptions" does not exist
>
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =
> org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
>
> spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
>
> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

Code works for

```
 import javax.persistence.*;
    
        @Table(name = "users")
        @Entity
        public class User {
        
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            @Column(name = "userID")
            private long userID;
        }
            
        @Table(name = "subscriptions")
        @Entity
        public class Subscription {
        
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            @Column(name = "subscriptionID")
            private long subscriptionID;
        
        }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please check if the table is created or if you get any exceptions when Hibernate creates the table?

Comment: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table subscriptions drop constraint FK5ju201bkc08up0b1x2x51mblu" via JDBC Statement

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thanks, you helped

Answer (score 2):

Just use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` instead of `create-drop`